# Create Json array in swift ui

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a checkbox in a list and on click of checkbox I want to create a Json array like this

```
{"nurseryData":[{"nurseryCode":"","SSOId":""},.....]} and so on
```

I have tried various approaches but I am not able to append the parameters on checkbox click.

Please suggest a way how to achieve it I am a beginner in swift ui.

```
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire
struct AddNurseryCard: View {
    @State private var checked = false
    let models : AddNurseryModels.Data
    
    var data: [String: Any] = [
        "nurseryData": [String : Any]()
    ]
 
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Image("nursery")
            Divider()
            VStack{
                if((models.isUrban!) != 0)
                {
                    Text(models.nurseryName! + " (U)")
            
                }else{
                    Text(models.nurseryName! + " (R)")
                }
                Text(models.rANGE_NAME!)
                if((models.isActiveForGGAY!) != 0)
                {
                    Text("Is Active For GGAY : Yes")
                }
                else{
                    Text("Is Active For GGAY : NO")
                }
        }
           
            CheckBoxView(checked: $checked).onAppear(){
                if((models.isActiveForGGAY) != 0)
                {
                   
                    checked = true
                    
                }
                else{
                    checked = false
                }
            }.onChange(of: checked, perform: { value in
                if(checked)
                {
                let result = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "profile")
                
                let profile = ProfileModels(dict: result as! [String : Any])
                let ssoId = (profile.data?[0].ssoid ?? "") as String
                let nurseryCode = models.nurseryCode!
                var existingItems = data["nurseryCode"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]()
                var param = ["ssoId":ssoId,"nurseryCode":nurseryCode]
                    
                param.merge(dict: param)
                  print()
                    
                    existingItems.append(param)
                                         print(existingItems)
               addNursery(params: param)
                    
                }
                
            })
            
          
    }
        Divider()
}
    func getArray(params:[[String: Any]]) -> [[String: Any]]
    {
        return params
    }
    func getChecked() -> Bool
    {
        return checked
    }
    func getNurseryCode() -> String
    
    {
        return models.nurseryCode!
    }
   
    func addNursery(params :[String:Any])
    {
        
        let url = Constants.init().devUrl + Api.init().addNursery
        
      
       
        
        let headers : HTTPHeaders = HTTPHeaders(["ApiKey" : Constants.init().apiKey])
        
        AF.request(url,method: .post,parameters: params, encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result{
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .success(let json):
            print(json)
            
            }
        }
        
    }
}
struct AddNurseryCard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddNurseryCard(models: AddNurseryModels.dat)
    }
}
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func merge(dict: [Key: Value]){
        for (k, v) in dict {
            updateValue(v, forKey: k)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but you should consider moving most of the logic to a separate class (view model) instead of doing everything in the view. Separation of concerns.

Comment: You may also want to consider SwiftyJSON: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON, it's much easier to work with.

Comment: Please explain why the “in swift UI” matters. I strongly recommend you move your attempt to create JSON into a separate function. And JSON should only be used to transmit or store/load data.

Comment: Tromgy: No need to use a third party library, Swift is quite capable of handling JSON very easily.

Comment: Why do you want to create a json? What do you want to do with it, once created?

Comment: I’ll write an answer for you. It will be quite in depth though. Just been out so haven’t been able to.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... the problem we have here is not one from SwiftUI specifically but more that there isn't really any design behind the code at all.

Let me preface this answer by saying I will be making several assumptions about some of your data as it's hard to determine what shape it has at the moment.

Going step by step.

### Modelling the data

Your current data model is

```
var data: [String: Any] = [
  "nurseryData": [String : Any]()
]
```

In Swift we should be avoiding `Any` as much as possible. And in fact, your data really has no shape at all here.

I'd suggest adding a new type like...

```
struct NewNursery: Codable {
  let nurseryCode: String
  let SSOId: String
}
```

and

```
struct SelectedNurseries: Codable {
  let nurseries: [NewNursery] = []
}
```

Using `Codable` will let you then use...

```
let jsonData = JSONEncdoer().encode(updloadData)
```

This allows you to remove all your merging and `[String: Any]` functions and types.

### View Model

We can also pack some of the complexity that you have in the view into a view model. You also seem to have a lot of forced unwrapping which is potentially dangerous. If you ever force unwrap something that is nil your app will crash. If you know it will never be nil then it shouldn't be optional in your data in the first place.

Lets create a view model that will contain some of the logic...

As a quick side comment. Calling something `Data` doesn't really give any clue as to what is inside it.

```
struct AddNurseryViewModel {
  let models: AddNurseryModels.Data // I'm really not sure what this is but I'll keep the same name you use.

  var nameSuffix: String {
    if let isUrban = models.isUrban,
      isUrban != 0 {
      return "U"
    } else {
      return "R"
    }
  }

  var isActiveForGgay: Bool {
    if let isActive = models.isActiveForGGAY,
      isActive != 0 {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  var ggayText: String {
    if isActiveForGgay {
      return "Is Active For GGAY : Yes"
    } else {
      return "Is Active For GGAY : No"
    }
  }
}
```

### Looking at the view with the new data

I'm really not 100% sure why there are so many `get...` functions? At a guess I'd say that you have come from a Java background possibly?

Anyway... let's look at rewriting the view now that we have a model. I'll also be using some more succinct syntax to achieve some of what you are doing.

```
struct AddNurseryCard: View {
  @State private var checked = false
  let viewModel: AddNurseryViewModel

  var selectedNurseries = SelectedNurseries()
 
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Image("nursery")
      Divider()
      VStack {
        Text("\(models.nurseryName!) \(viewModel.nameSuffix)")
        Text(models.rANGE_NAME!)
        Text(viewModel.ggayText)
      }
           
      CheckBoxView(checked: $checked)
        .onAppear() { checked = viewModel.isActiveForGgay }
        .onChange(of: checked) { value in
          nurserySelected()
        }
  
    }
    Divider()
  }

  func nurserySelected() {
    if(checked) {
      // I'm really struggling to understand some of this but you need to apply my same thoughts of data modelling here.
      // I will write the code as it "should" be but you will need to model it for this to work.

      let profile = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "profile")
            
      let ssoId = profile.ssoid // don't use [String: Any] for things like this
      let nurseryCode = models.nurseryCode!

      var newNursery = NewNursery(nurseryCode: nurseryCode, ssoId: ssoId)
                    
      selectedNurseries.nurseries.append(newNursery)
                    
      addNursery(nursery: newNursery)
    }
  }
  
  // This whole function should really be in a separate file. It's nothing to do with the view.
  func addNursery(nursery: NewNursery)
  {
    let url = Constants.init().devUrl + Api.init().addNursery
        
    let headers : HTTPHeaders = HTTPHeaders(["ApiKey" : Constants.init().apiKey])
        
    AF.request(url,method: .post,parameters: nursery, encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
      switch response.result{
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
      case .success(let json):
        print(json)    
      }
    }      
  }
}
```

It really pays to try and model your data in a way that works for what you are doing.

Not spending the time to model the data like this leads to code that is complicated and not very readable/maintainable.

The code in this answer isn't the only way to write this view and there are other approaches that make this a lot nicer and more succinct and more elegant.

This is just an initial pass at how you might begin to improve what you already have.